# Latex misread the equation and marks an error

Tags: equations

I am trying to write the equation below but latex marks an error saying that there is no line here to end. I have tried commands as align and split but they do not work. I would appreciate it if someone has a suggestion to fix this problem.

```
\begin{equation} 
    \label{eq:standard_curve}
    \begin{align}
                $\Phi_\text{e}$  = K_\text{m} \[ \int_{\SI{780}{\nano\meter}}^{\SI{380}{\nano\meter}} $V_\lambda$ $\Phi_{e,\lambda}$ \,$d\lambda$ \]  
     \end{align}
    
    \end{equation}
```

[image: equation to write]

Comment: It's wrong to have `align` inside `equation`. Remove `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` (don't leave blank lines) and also the `$` characters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have whatever to align?

Comment: Oh, also `\[` and `\]` should be `[` and `]`.

Comment: And also your use `\text` is wrong in two ways, firstly it is shear luck that `_\text` actually works without `{} `, secondly `\text` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start `\begin{equation}`, TeX goes into “math mode”. Also `align` does, so you shouldn't use it inside `equation` (its job is doing alignments, which you don't seem to have).

Since you're already in math mode, `$` is disallowed: it is not a way to make funny symbols, but to start *inline math mode*.

If you want square brackets, type `[` and `]`, not `\[` and `\]`. The backslash is only needed for *braces* {}, that should be typed in as `\{` and `\}`, because `{` and `}` have a different usage in TeX. You also need to make them bigger to encompass the integral sign.

Fixed code:

```
\begin{equation} 
    \label{eq:standard_curve}
    \Phi_{\mathrm{e}} = K_{\mathrm{m}} \biggl[ \int_{\SI{380}{\nano\meter}}^{\SI{780}{\nano\meter}} V_\lambda \Phi_{\mathrm{e},\lambda} \,d\lambda \biggr]
\end{equation}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the brackets don't seem necessary here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
    \label{eq:standard_curve}
    \Phi_{\mathrm{e}} = K_{\mathrm{m}} \int_{\SI{380}{\nano\meter}}^{\SI{780}{\nano\meter}} V_\lambda \Phi_{\mathrm{e},\lambda} \,d\lambda
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You beat me to this answer by a few seconds. :-)

Comment: I would have done the integral from 380 nm to 780 nm

Comment: @DDuck Oh, I just took the OP's code and didn't look at the picture. I'll fix.